# aspx file does not contain a definition for function, definition in connected aspx.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, code-behind

I am trying to have a onclick for a button, but I'm getting

> 'ASP.views_home_index_aspx' does not contain a definition for
> 'btnCreateOrder_Click' and no extension method 'btnCreateOrder_Click'
> accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.views_home_index_aspx' could
> be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code:

Index.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" %>
*THERE IS A COMMENT ABOUT THE INHERIT NEAR THE END OF MY POST*
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
    <table id="productTable">
    
    </table>
    <asp:Label ID="testMessage" runat="server" Text="fail"></asp:Label>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
    </p>

    <asp:Button ID="btnCreateOrder" runat="server" Text="Create Order" onclick="btnCreateOrder_Click" />

</asp:Content>
```

Index.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyProject.Views.Home
{
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Testing");
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("data/products.xml");

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(reader.Name);

        }


        int numRows = 21;
        int numCells = 4;
        for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < numRows; rowNum++)
        {
            TableCell cel = new TableCell();

        }
    }

    public void btnCreateOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Testing");
    }

}
```

On a semi related note, I also can't get the Page_Load to run on page load. (hence the debug "testing").

*INHERITANCE COMMENT*
It was suggested that I change inheritance to `MyProject.Views.Home.Index` however I need the System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage in order to deal with the MVC layout, without it I get :

> System.InvalidOperationException: The view at
> '~/Views/Home/Index.aspx' must derive from ViewPage,
> ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl.

So... Yeah, unless I'm supposed to put my functions elsewhere like in the Controllers file (I'm new to Visual Studio) not sure what to do.

I've seen that changing the inheritance could fix it but if I set it to the proper file directive it breaks it (proper would by MyProject.Views.Home) it returns

> "Could not load type 'MyProject.Views.Home'."

so not sure what's going on there. Other than that, yes they're in the same folder and yes they're attached and obviously it's set to its codebehind.

Comment: MVC and Web Forms are a completely different kettle of fish. MVC uses Controlers and Web Forms user code behind pages. I would go with one or the other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have wrong value in the page's `Inherits` attribute. The actual code-behind class should be there:

```
Inherits="MyProject.Views.Home.Index"
```

Comment: The problem here is I have to inherit from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage because of the MVC layout, and from my research there's no way to inherit from two sources, would I instead do my .cs actions elsewhere (like in the HomeController.cs file that is what the System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage is used to access)?

Comment: @user2172534, what you can try is inheriting your code-behind class for `Index` page not from `System.Web.UI.Page` but from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`. As a page attribute `Inherits` has a slightly different meaning, see [the description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @user2172534, by the way, proper value for `Inherits` is not a namespace as you have suggested in the edit. It is a class, so the value should be `MyProject.Views.Home.Index`.

Comment: I'll have to go about learning all this Inherits stuff haha, thanks for the direction and help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Index.aspx page isn't wired up to use the same class that is being used in your CodeBehind file.

Trying changing your `Inherits` attribute in Index.aspx from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` to `MyProject.Views.Home.Index`.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work since this is in MVC format, so maybe I'm supposed to put the functions elsewhere? See in my post the section marked *INHERITANCE COMMENT* near the end for more info :)

Answer (score 0):

Your page is Inheriting `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` when it should be `MyProject.Views.Home.Index`

Change that whole top line on the .aspx page to be

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
Inherits="MyProject.Views.Home.Index" 
AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" %>
```